# Simbolos extraños a la hora de compilar

Tags: c++, array

tengo una inquietud, cuando compilo el programa a la hora de dar los resultados, me salen uno símbolos que no tienen nada que ver con lo que estoy haciendo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

acá esta mi código:

```
int main() {
    char vector1[25];
    char vector2[25];
    char vectores;

    cout << "Pon una oracion: ";
    cin.getline(vector1,25);
    cout << "Pon otra oracion: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(vector2, 25);
    
    for(int i = 0; i <= 25; i++) {
        cout << vector1[i];
    }
    
    for(int h = 0; h <= 25; h++) {
        cout << vector2[h];
    }
```

Comment: El problema es que imprimes todo el arreglo, aunque la cadena estilo C que guarda cin.getline puede ocupar menos espacio. `std::cout` soporta escribir cadenas estilo C así que puedes usar `std::cout << vector1` directamente. Si lees una linea no es necesario `cin.ignore()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sabes la diferencia entre compilar y ejecutar. Compilar es crear el programa que será ejecutado; los programas compilados se pueden ejecutar.

Los símbolos extraños que describes salen al ejecutar, así que no aparecen "*a la hora de compilar*".

---

El lenguaje [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) sólo inicializa las variables si se le pide explícitamente, en caso contrario deja las variables con un valor residual. En tu caso, las dos formaciones están sin inicializar:

```
char vector1[25];
char vector2[25];
```

Eso implica que tendrán valores residuales que, al ser de tipo carácter (`char`) se mostrarían en pantalla como *símbolos extraños*. Puedes evitar eso inicializando las formaciones como un conjunto de datos vacío:

```
char vector1[25]{};
char vector2[25]{};
```

Esto evitará los *símbolos extraños*, pero también los evitaría el no mostrar más caracteres de los necesarios, si leíste cuatro caracteres con `hola` ¿por qué imprimes 25?

Es más, si estás leyendo cadenas de texto ¿Po qué no leer sobre un `std::string`?

```
std::string vector1;
std::string vector2;

std::cout << "Pon una oracion: ";
std::getline(std::cin, vector1);
std::cout << "Pon otra oracion: ";
std::cin.ignore();
std::getline(std::cin, vector2);

std::cout << vector1 << vector2;
```